# YiiBoilerPlate project showing 404 not found error

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, yii, virtualhost

By referring following site:

```
http://myprogrammingtut.blogspot.in/2013/04/step-by-step-setup-yiiboilerplate.html
```

I have created two virtual host in my ubuntu 12.10 os. i.e

```
yiibackend for yii backend and
yiifrontend for yii frontend
```

I have added path for them in my vhost like:

```
ServerName yiibackend
DocumentRoot /var/www/yiibootstrap/backend/www
```

and

```
ServerName yiifrontend
DocumentRoot /var/www/yiibootstrap/frontend/www
```

But when I am trying open

```
http://backend.local
```

its working and showing the home page but when I am clicking on any another links its showing me following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /site/page/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at yiibackend Port 80
```

Please help to solve this. I am very new in yii framework and dont have much idea about its structure.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled? And if so, are `.htaccess` rules properly configured? Your problem is clearly apache rewrite related.

Comment: @PeterM : Where can I check this because the yiiboilerplate project contain two .htaccess i.e. in frontend folder and in backend folder.

Comment: I have checked again and its actually contain 6 .htaccess files

Comment: Check that in `www` dir, in frontend and backend. Also, one more to check: are `.htaccess` interpreted by server? Put some garbage into it, and see if you have apache error 500. If not, it means your apache ignores `.htaccess`

Comment: Following is my .htaccess file in frontend and backend. `RewriteEngine on

# If you are in a sub folder of your web root you
# might have to enable something like this:
#
# RewriteBase /~antonio/app/frontend/www

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

# Tmp for large data uploads 
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 60M
php_value post_max_size 60M
</IfModule>`

Comment: @PeterM: How can I interprete it with server?

Comment: To enable parsing of `.htaccess` files you need `AllowOverride All`, here is more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html in ubuntu it is by default set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the index.php 
so instead of calling directly /site/login
call index.php/site/login

to remove the index.php , you have to add 
something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

or check out 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/